# mySql replace only a single word in a column

Tags: mysql

Using mySql alone, I'm trying to replace the word microsoft with microsoft-corp.

I tried using this sql, `update names set names = replace(names,'microsoft','microsoft-corp')`, but that replaces each and every `microsoft`. Is there a way to get it to replace only the word microsoft?

**Original data**

```
"id"    "names"
"1"     "/microsoft"
"2"     "/microsoft/microsoft-word"
"3"     "/microsoft/microsoft-word/microsoft-word-tutorials"
"4"     "/microsoft/microsoft-word/microsoft-word-tutorials/examples"

"id"    "names"
"1"     "microsoft >"
"2"     "microsoft > microsoft-word"
"3"     "microsoft > microsoft-word > microsoft-word-tutorials"
"4"     "microsoft > microsoft-word > microsoft-word-tutorials > examples"
```

**Expected correct results**

```
"id"    "names"
"1"     "/microsoft-corp"
"2"     "/microsoft-corp/microsoft-word"
"3"     "/microsoft-corp/microsoft-word/microsoft-word-tutorials"
"4"     "/microsoft-corp/microsoft-word/microsoft-word-tutorials/examples"
```

**Current incorrect results using my query above**

```
"id"    "names"
"1"     "/microsoft-corp"
"2"     "/microsoft-corp/microsoft-corp-word"
"3"     "/microsoft-corp/microsoft-corp-word/microsoft-corp-word-tutorials"
"4"     "/microsoft-corp/microsoft-corp-word/microsoft-corp-word-tutorials/examples"
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
update names set names = replace(names,'/microsoft/','/microsoft-corp/')

update names set names = '/microsoft-corp' where names = '/microsoft'

update names set names = replace(names,'microsoft >','microsoft-corp >')
```

Comment: Those `/` aren't always there. Another column does not have slashes.

Comment: @jmenezes - in future can you make that clear in your question. i.e. by providing sample data that covers these different possibilities.

Comment: @jmenezes - Probably, but can you post all the variations in the question?

Comment: I did that. It's the same thing, but without the slashes.

Comment: @jmenezes - see my updated answer, it's untested at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this in two passes, although you might be able to it in one pass.

```
update names set names = replace(names,'/microsoft/','/microsoft-corp/');
update names set names = '/microsoft-corp' where names = '/microsoft';
```